# How can I make the my button's relative location (to a video) the same?

Tags: html, css

I have a mute button that goes on top of a video, but I don't know how I can make sure that the button always is by the bottom right of the video.

I've tried making the position absolute, but that doesn't help much.

HTML

```
<div id="videopart">

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls muted autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<button onclick="toggleMute();" type="button" id="mute">Toggle sound</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#mute {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#videopart {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myVideo {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I want my button to be in the same spot (relative to the video), no matter what the size of the video is. Can you please help me?

Comment: simply use: position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; (you can adjust position) and you can remove margins.
Here the button will be on the bottom right corner of your .videopart element

Answer (score 1):

For positioning the button you will have to set the positions on the X and Y axes. Also, don't forget to set the z-index of `#mute` higher then the z-index of `#myVideo`. In the example beneath the position of `#mute` is relative to `#videopart`

```
#mute {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: It's because af the absolute positioned video element in combination with the height of the wrapper. Fixed it on https://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/yn1or6p9/

Answer (score 0):

```
#mute {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:0; /* OR 20px */
    z-index:100;
}
```

Use this to posicionate the element at `absolute` with `right` 20px and `top` 0px or 20px

Answer (score 0):

change **position:absolute** to **position:relative** in #myvideo and position #mute using **bottom:0** and **right:0**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div id="videopart">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls muted autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <button onclick="toggleMute();" type="button" id="mute">Toggle sound</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

I haven't used css, but if you want any other styles you can use

Comment: I do not think using table elements is good practice to position elements.